# Why is the equation governing image formation in reflection of mirrors and refraction of lenses the same?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

From this article by [physics classroom](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-3/The-Mirror-Equation), we see that mirror equation is just:
$$ \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$$
With magnification:

$$ m = \frac{- d_i}{d_o}$$

And in this article [for refraction](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-5/The-Mathematics-of-Lenses),

$$ \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$$

With magnification,

$$ m = \frac{- d_i}{d_o}$$

This suggests that refraction through lens and reflection through mirror are pretty much analogous the same process as the relation governing the relationship image and object distance are the same.

Is there an intuition / understanding as to why both equations come out same in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Can you construct the image of an object by a lens and by a concave mirror, than you can see, that the laws, once given the focal point are the same. or look it up in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curved_mirror#Concave_mirrors